# How can I generate more attention for this question?

Tags: discussion

[How do search engines implement fuzzy search?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144873/64055)

After very brief period of initial interest and upvotes, this question seems to have been dead for months.

How can I generate more attention for this question? My past experience has always been that bounties don't work (I don't have much rep to put up a strong incentive anyway).

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268105/3310334 recommends

> Promote the question elsewhere on the web - Twitter, Google+, Facebook or where ever you can find topic experts.

Where on the web might search engine topic experts be?

Answer (score 4):

I see two and a half problems with your question:

1. It's very broad: any somewhat completely answer is likely textbook-sized.
2. You are asking about a proprietary product. Nobody but Google employees know exactly how they do it, and they most likely can not talk publically about it.
3. As a consequence, you're asking for speculation on how they *may* be doing it.

You'd likely have more success by addressing these issues.

One idea would be to formulate an algorithms question, specifying rather closely what the expected output is given a few descriptive input example. Then, experts can propose methods that solve the problem at hand.
(Plus, you'll most likely gain further insight phrasing your question that way.)

Comment: I don't care (or know) enough about the details of the input and output to want to restrict answerers to awkward and/or impossible problems

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback though, I will try to ask a question that asks after an algorithm with examples

Answer (score 3):

You can generate attention by adding a bounty. You should have enough reputation to do so. But if you don't want to spend it, good places to spread the word would be The tavern on the meta, Webmasters.SE, Superuser, Ubuntu, Operations research, SO, etc. Outside of SE, Twitter, Linkedin, Reddit, blogs like substack, Bing, Microsoft answers etc are good choices.